# JavaFx Text Tooltip mouseover doesn't get any response

Tags: javafx, text, tooltip, fxml

I set a tooltip on a text element in JavaFx, everything works as long as I do not hover mouse on the text, the tooltip does not get displayed.

```
 <Text layoutX="329.0" layoutY="202.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Tcond[C]" textAlignment="CENTER">
      <Tooltip text="'%Empty_Bundle'"/>
  </Text>
```

That's the fxml code which should create a tooltip on this text.

How to fix it without creating assign text to an object in my view controller and setting on the tooltip by using .setTooltp() method?

Comment: "That's the fxml code which should create a tooltip on this text.". No: the `@DefaultProperty` for a [`Text`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html) is the `text` property, so this would try to set the text to the provided tooltip. `Text` doesn't have a `setTooltip(...)` method: you need to do this in the controller with [`Tooltip.install(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.html#install-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.control.Tooltip-). You could use a `Label`, which does have a `setTooltip`, so you can set it in FXML.

Comment: So instead Text I should use Label yes?

Comment: If a `Label` works for what you need. Or just set the tooltip in the controller, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FXML, if you embed one instance element directly inside another, without a property element, it is used to set the property annotated as the `@DefaultProperty` on the outer instance element.

If you check the [documentation for `Text`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html) you will see that the default property is `"text"`: so your FXML is equivalent to

```xml
<Text layoutX="329.0" layoutY="202.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Tcond[C]" textAlignment="CENTER">
    <text>
        <Tooltip text="'%Empty_Bundle'"/>
    </text>
</Text>
```

In other words, you are trying to set the text of your `Text` object to the tooltip.

`Text` doesn't actually have a `setTooltip(...)` method at all; that method is defined in the `Control` class, of which `Text` is not a subclass. The only way to set a tooltip on a `Text` instance is by using the [`Tooltip.installTooltip(...)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.html#install-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.control.Tooltip-), which you can only call from the controller (there is no FXML equivalent to calling this static method).

Your other option, if it works, would be to replace the `Text` with a `Label`:

```xml
<Label layoutX="329.0" layoutY="202.0" text="Tcond[C]" textAlignment="CENTER">
    <tooltip>
        <Tooltip text="'%Empty_Bundle'"/>
    </tooltip>
</Label>
```

Note that `Label` does not allow you to directly configure the `stroke`, as a `Text` does, so you would lose that functionality (or at least have to use CSS instead).

Comment: Ok it works, I had to change to Label and add <tooltip></tooltip>